# The return of string find function in cpp

Tags: c++, string

Is there a case where the string::find function return -1 ?
that code I have seen a lot while surveying a code for XML_Editor
and I can't understand the code

```
if(temp.find("<") == -1){}
```

The above code is an example of what I mean
I hope someone help , thanks :)

Comment: I always find cppreference a good source of documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find (-1 is 'hidden' behind `npos`)

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::find` returns `npos` when it cannot find its parameter. [`npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) is defined as:

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

However, note that `size_type` is unsigned. Hence, one should not use `-1` to check the value returend from `find`. The value of `npos` is the largest value representable as `size_type` and `-1` is just a way to initialize `npos` with that value. When checking the value returned from `find` one should always use `std::string::npos` rather than `-1`, because `-1` is a signed literal:

```
if(temp.find("<") == std::string::npos){
    // < was not found in temp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` seems to return `std::string::npos` when it cannot find  the input value, and `std::string::npos` is defined to be `size_t(-1)`, but I think it's a better practice to use `if(temp.find("<") == temp.npos){}`

Answer (score 0):

It would be more correct and clear to write

```
if(temp.find("<") == std::string::npos){}
```

where `npos` is usually defined like `( std::string::size_type )( -1 )`. In the expression in the if statement

```
if(temp.find("<") == -1){}
```

the integer constant `-1` having the type int is converted to the unsigned integer type `std::string::size_type`  due to the usual arithmetic conversions and as such represents the maximum value for an object of the type
`std::string::size_type`. This value signals that the operation was not successful.